# $.ajax responseText differs from responseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, responsetext

I am seeing a difference in what is returned when comparing the responseJSON and responseText properties of my ajax request.

In the image below, you see that referencing the responseJSON excludes the "properties" property.  When I parse and use the responseText, the "properties" property is included.

[image]
[image]

I've not encountered this kind of weirdness before, anyone have any suggestions or thoughts as to why this is occurring?

**Edit 1:** The properties object is undefined when attempting to access it directly from the responseJSON.  See below image:

[image]

**Edit 2:** I am unable to replicate this issue in my jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/madChemist/4hd9cz1g/).  I am using jQuery version 2.1.4 incase that helps to diagnose things.

The responseJSON is equivalent to the parsed responseText in my fiddle:

```
Parsed responseText properties - {"border-color":"cyan","border-style":"dashed","border-width":"5px"}
Unoutched responseJSON properties - {"border-color":"cyan","border-style":"dashed","border-width":"5px"}
```

The two differences I see between my environment and this one are primarily that the ajax request type is a GET not POST. The data in the fiddle was trimmed compared to what I am loading in my environment.  I tested both trimmed & untrimmed which produced no difference in my findings.

**Edit 3:** I've taken some screenshots of my code to demonstrate what I am attempting to do.  The screenshots I took originally were logged while I had my breakpoint on the second assertion in the unit test module.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've never heard of the responseJSON property... any idea/documentation on what creates it? haven't found it in the usual places i look.

Comment: @KevinB take a look at the Data Types section of the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: If you access that object directly when using responseJSON, does it exist? (rules out console trickery)

Comment: @KevinB I am unable to access the property directly when drilling through responseJSON.  I've attached a screenshot of my attempt.

Comment: I tried to replicate the error in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8su2/1039/) but all 3 responses are ok here. Could you try to replicate the error in a Fiddle?

Comment: Unsuccessful in my attempts to replicate the issue on jsFiddle so far.  The big difference is the request type (My GET vs jsFiddles' POST).  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/madChemist/4hd9cz1g/

Comment: Your ajax handler code does not modify the `.responseJSON` object, does it?

Comment: @Bergi I am not modifying the responseJSON.  I am setting a variable to the responseJSON and performing comparisons with what is returned for my unit tests.  No manipulation of the response object.

Comment: @Mad-Chemist: Can you show us that code? We may be able to figure out what's going on from that. Until then, if the issue is unreproducible, we will hardly be able to help you with it. Maybe tell us more about your environment as well.

Comment: @Bergi I've attached two screenshots of the code in my project.  The first method (loadLocalProject) returns the ajax request made in the second screenshot.  QUnit's DIFF shows the properties property missing (see first screenshots attached to post.  They were taken with my breakpoint on the second assertion.  I was able to manually verify the QUnit diff).

Comment: Please post code as code, not as a screenshot. And please show your implementation of `setUpLayout` and `generateLayour` (and anything they depend upon)

Comment: `setUpLayout` and `generateLayout` do not modify the parameter passed in.  A local variable is created using `$.extend({}, loaded);` .  Playing with the unit test more, this may not actually be an issue with jQuery's parsing, but rather QUnit.  `var a = JSON.stringify(loaded); var b = JSON.stringify(result.data); console.log(a === b); // true` indicates that `a` and `b` are identical.  The next assertion still fails though: `assert.equal(a, b, "Freshly generated export is the same as initially loaded in import.");`

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't see how reiterating Bergi's above point adds anything here.  The code in question was added as an answer prior to your comment.  See below.

Answer (score 0):

My tests are passing now.  My issue may actually be with QUnit's scoping.  The odd behavior above went away when I made these changes to my test:

```
QUnit.test("Method exportLayout", 2, function (assert) {
    var done = assert.async();

    $('body').append('<div id="application" style="display:none;"></div>');
    var controller = new ApplicationController();
    controller.createApplicationWorkspace();

    var load = controller.loadLocalProject(); // Pulls in local JSON file
    load.complete(function (request) {
        var loaded = request.responseJSON; //$.parseJSON(request.responseText); 
        controller.setUpLayout($.parseJSON(request.responseText)); // Creates workspace from saved state

        var result = controller.generateLayout(); // Generates Object.  Data property should equal what was loaded in originally.
        assert.ok(result !== undefined && result.data !== undefined, "Application controller generates layout response in a proper format.");
        assert.deepEqual(loaded, result.data, "Freshly generated export is the same as initially loaded in import.");

        // Teardown
        setTimeout(function () {
            controller.layout.destroy();
            $('#application').remove();
            done();
        }, 0);

    });
});
```

Specifically made this change:

```
controller.setUpLayout($.parseJSON(request.responseText));
```

The `setUpLayout` method is a few hundred lines long, but this is how it begins:

```
    setUpLayout: function (loaded) {
        if (typeof loaded !== 'object' || !loaded.hasOwnProperty('rows')) {
            throw new Error('Invalid format for loaded paramater in setUpLayout method.');
        }

        var initial_mode = TE.Application.reqres.request('editor:mode');
        TE.Application.vent.trigger('editor:toggle_mode', true);

        var layout = $.extend({}, loaded);
        var rowCollection = this.layout.editor.currentView.rows.currentView;
        var rows = layout.rows; // Once stashed in a var,

        ...
        // Doesn't make use of `loaded` parameter.  Only modifications are to `layout` variable.

    }
```

I feel like there may still be something else at work here, but I wanted to update this post with what I had just found.  Hoping someone else may be able to notice something that I did not.